# How to let Flash app communicate with server?

Tags: javascript, flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3

What's an easy and secure way to let my Flash app communicate with my back-end server?

The Flash app, which is a video player, should retrieve the person's username and send back an ID. How would I do this?

Note: Back-end is written in Javascript.

Comment: Back-end in Javascript?  Are you talking about NodeJS?

Comment: And what's the data protocol? JSON? XML? AMF?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect flash with JS to actionscript use [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6). If you want to connect to e.g. PHP use [NetConnection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetConnection.html) or [UrlLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html)

Comment: You can also use `HTTPService` or `RemoteObject` too.

Answer (score 1):

I've used XML-RPC in a Flash client before. I've gotten it to work pretty well too.

I've personally used this Action Script 3 implementation:

http://danielmclaren.com/2007/08/03/xmlrpc-for-actionscript-30-free-library

Of course, the server I was talking with was Java/Tomcat. However, I'm pretty sure there are XML-RPC implementations for JavaScript; a quick search found this:

http://phpxmlrpc.sourceforge.net/jsxmlrpc/

Don't know how much setup/overhead it would be for you server-wise, but I've had success with that protocol.

Comment: Json-rpc might be just what I need. I'll look into it.